# How to insert nested array data with parent id using recursive function in php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "label": "Apricots",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Blackberries",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Blueberries",
            "children": [
                {
                    "label": "Blackcurrant",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "label": "Blackcurrant blanc Petits Grains",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Blackcurrant of Alexandria",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "label": "Normal",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "Hanepoot",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Blackcurrant of Scanzorosciate",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "Coconut Meat",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "label": "Clementine",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "label": "Cherries",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "label": "Cranberries",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Gooseberries",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Honeydew Melon",
            "children": [
                {
                    "label": "Java-Plum",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "label": "Lemon",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the nested array data, how I can insert the parent item and as well as children item with the parent id. I already try with nested foreach loop it's working but If the child item has no limit then it's unpredictable how many times I have to loop through. please help to make it with a recursive function.

Comment: Is this generated from SQL data? If so resources could help this and the data has no id's so what defines a parent_id?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. this data not generated from SQL it's API data. I have done the code where I using foreach loop but I want to make it recursive

Comment: Can you show the models, because i think there is an easy approach if it is model and relationship based.

Answer (score 0):

First, select the parent records

```
$parents = <<Your model>>::where('parent_id',null)->get();
```

Then loop through the parents and populate children recursively

```
foreach ($parents as $key=>$parent){
   $parents[$key]["children"] = getChildren($parent->id);
}

function getChildren($parent_id){
    $children = <<Your model>>::where('parent_id',$parent_id)->get();
    if ($children->count() > 0){
        foreach ($children as $key=>$child){
            $children[$key]['children'] = getChildren($child->id);
        }
    }
    return $children;
}
```